# Since I recently upgraded to KDE Plasma 5 latest, natural scroll won't work

Tags: linux, scrolling, opensuse, kde-plasma-5

Where can I find the reference documentation for kdeglobals config file?

System settings' GUI control for reverse scrolling has absolutely no effect, since I recently ran zypper up and zypper patch. The kdeglobals [KDE] section makes no reference to Reverse Scroll Direction. Since I can't find a spec, I've no idea what to use as the attribute name. I tried 'ReverseScrollDirection=true' but that didn't work. Where do the KDE/Plasma developers keep their specs, docs & designs and what is the right attribute name?

Thanks

```
[KDE]
AutoSelectDelay=-1
ChangeCursor=true
ColorScheme=Breeze
DoubleClickInterval=400
SingleClick=true
StartDragDist=4
StartDragTime=500
WheelScrollLines=3
contrast=4
```

Comment: Same here. Even worse: Reversing it via `xmodmap` takes effect in most applications, but not some `kde` apps.